# Can I prevent people from commenting on my Facebook Photos?

Tags: facebook

I know you can prevent them from posting on my wall, but can I stop them from posting comments on pictures?

Alternatively can I make it so that no one can see my photo albums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this can be done if you do the following:

1. Click on the "Edit Info" link after
   you log in
2. On the left nav bar click on "Apps"
3. Click on "Edit Settings" in your
   Photos App
4. At the bottom of the dialog box in
   TINY print you can click a link
   called "modify privacy controls"
5. At the bottom of this page you can
   click "Customize Settings"
6. FINALLY look for the heading titled
   "Can comment on posts" and select
   "Customize" in the drop down list. 
   From here you can select "Only me"

I'm not sure if I'm making this harder than it needs to be or if Facebook intentionally makes it this difficult...

Comment: I don't see "Edit Info" on the Home page.

Comment: i dont see Edit Settings on photo app

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has made some changes to the Privacy Control Center. One of the features that was removed was the "Can comment on posts" feature. There is an option to approve tags that appear on your timeline, I am unsure whether they will extend this to comments in the future.

For more information see,

- http://www.facebook.com/about/sharing
- http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=199415346770069

To prevent users from seeing a Photo Album go to

> facebook.com/*yourusername*/photos

And hover on the gear at the bottom right of every album you want to change the audience.

[image: Audience change for Photo Albums]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the gear with the drop-down to edit the settings appears top-right, rather than bottom. It is worth noting that one of the options is a check-box for 'friends of those tagged'. Uncheck this to limit your albums to friends only.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, so that people can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings icon on the top-right -> Click on "Privacy settings" -> Click on "Followers" followed by "Follower comments" -> Chose "Friends" or "Friends of Friends" depending on your own preference.